# Formatting a bootstrap 5 table with scrollable large PRE block in a cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to figure out what I need to get this table formatted like I expect. I have one cell that has a large block (JSON object).  I'd like that block to either wrap to fit the enclosing TD, or have the contents of that TD scroll without causing the table to grow past the screen width.

Here's a jsfiddle showing an example of what I'm doing.

I would like the contents of the cell with colspan=4 to have its contents be scrollable within the cell.

https://jsfiddle.net/y8gzqpv5/1/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <!--!-->
          <th scope="col">
            <input type="checkbox">
          </th>
          <!--!-->
          <th scope="col">Message ID</th>
          <!--!-->
          <th scope="col">Created Date (UTC)</th>
          <th scope="col" class="clickable"><!--!-->Message Type<span>⌃</span></th>
          <!--!-->
          <!--!-->
          <th scope="col">Trace ID</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <!--!-->
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <!--!-->
          <td rowspan="2">
            <input type="checkbox"> 
          </td>
          <td>64bfe115407c62030d67c3bf</td>
          <!--!-->
          <td>7/25/2023 2:49:57 PM</td>
          <!--!-->
          <td>MyEventType</td>
          <!--!-->
          <td>5d32270e-b0a3-416c-9eb3-5e1006376850</td> 
        </tr>
        <!--!-->
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <div class="overflow-scroll">
              <pre>
                <code class="language-json" style="overflow: auto; white-space: pre; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: break-spaces;">{
  "TraceId": "5d32270e-b0a3-416c-9eb3-5e1006376850",
  "Key": "6b777e8f-882e-4a53-8ba0-64eca033c13c",
  "Type": "LongNameOfSomeParsedEventType",
  "Payload": "{\u0022AggregateUuid\u0022:\u00226b00de8f-882e-4a53-8ba0-64eca033c13c\u0022,\u0022Version\u0022:0,\u0022ParsedDate\u0022:\u00222023-07-24T21:58:39.1822492\u002B00:00\u0022,\u0022NumberRecordsParsed\u0022:2}",
  "SqsReceiptHandle": "AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002AQEzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzI002/Hfj8nST"
}</code>
              </pre>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tried a few variations of scrolling / clipping / hidden content but can't get it rendered correctly.

Comment: Try this in your css:                                                                                                
 <style type="text/css">
 td {
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -pre-wrap; 

}
table { 
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%
}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to change table layout like the following:

```css
.table {
  table-layout: fixed
}
```

The `fixed` layout ensure the table doesn't exceed the width you specified (100%). You can read more about it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout). Here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmad/3mdayn5q/)